# No project for "F# Application" in VS Express 2012 for Web

Tags: f#

I installed the [F# Tools for Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=FSharpVWD11). When I select *New Project* I expected to see *F# Application* in the list of Visual F# templates but all I see is *F# Library* and *F# Tutorial*.

I say I expected it because I see it referenced in the book Programming F# 3.0 by Chris Smith.

Any suggestions for getting the *F# Application* template in the list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no F# Application template in the VS Express 2012 Web edition but you should be able to create one easily by adding an F# library project and then going to the project properties and specifying the output type as Console Application in the Application tab.

The following short video from Jon Harrop shows how to create a Windows application: [WPF desktop GUI app development in F# with VS Express 2012 for Web](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4R9EfFNgLU)

The process is the same for a console application.

Answer (score 6):

I got F# from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34675), and I installed the extensions (Tools -> Extensions and Updates) shown below:

[image: Extensions and Updates]

I can now create the following types of projects in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web:

[image: Project templates]

Jon Harrop's videos are well worth the viewing, of course.

**EDIT**

The second image is scaled down and the text is illegible.  The project templates under `Visual F# -> Windows` are:

1. F# Library
2. F# Library (Class Library)
3. F# Windows App (Service)
4. F# Windows App (WinForms)
5. F# Windows App (WPF)
6. F# Windows Console App
7. F# Tutorial

Just to complete the list, here are the other project types:

`Visual F# -> Silverlight`

1. F# Silverlight Library

`ASPNET`

1. F# and C# Web Application (ASP.NET MVC 4)

`Service`

1. F# and C# Web Service (ASP.NET, WSDL)